# How many days have you visited Travel.SE?

Tags: discussion, fun

How many days have you visited in total? can you beat my number?

Share your number and let's see.

[image]

Comment: "Only" 914...! ;)

Comment: I've only got 2096, despite being a member here for 12 years and 2 months

Answer (score 3):

[Willeke](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/27650/willeke)
Member for 8 years, 11 months
Last seen 54 secs ago

Visited 3163 days, 2142 consecutive

I think I did not do too bad, not that I think I win the overall.

Comment: I now know I am not the user with the highest number of days, I leave it to them to mention it themselves.